# Genesis theme search function broken

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm working with a Wordpress install for a client's intranet build.

Every theme I use has functional search, and uses the same string: "http://www.clientsite.com/?s=development"

Whenever I activate the Genesis theme, the search just goes to a blank page.

Is there anyone who knows where I might look to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Start enabling wordpress debug https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Try to use [WordPress Custom Search Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcs-wp-custom-search/). Hope this will help you.